# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, typeerror

I wanted to change this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136) and use my own data and just changed the file name in the function

```
chart("ohne_postionanträge_monatlich_erst2015.csv", "orange");
```

this is my csv file

```
key,value,date
Afghanistan,1129,01/01/15
Afghanistan,969,02/01/15
Afghanistan,885,03/01/15
Afghanistan,1119,04/01/15
Afghanistan,1151,05/01/15
Afghanistan,2051,06/01/15
Afghanistan,2104,07/01/15
Afghanistan,2270,08/01/15
Afghanistan,2724,09/01/15
Afghanistan,3770,10/01/15
Albanien,1598,01/01/15
Albanien,1735,02/01/15
Albanien,2955,03/01/15
Albanien,4743,04/01/15
Albanien,4864,05/01/15
Albanien,5837,06/01/15
Albanien,7547,07/01/15
Albanien,8234,08/01/15
Albanien,6624,09/01/15
Albanien,4549,10/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,370,02/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,380,03/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,472,04/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,382,05/01/15
Eritrea,620,01/01/15
Eritrea,350,02/01/15
Eritrea,306,03/01/15
Eritrea,362,04/01/15
Eritrea,612,05/01/15
Eritrea,1063,06/01/15
Eritrea,1209,07/01/15
Eritrea,978,08/01/15
Eritrea,1113,09/01/15
Eritrea,1201,10/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,21679,01/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,22775,02/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,28681,03/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,24504,04/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,23758,05/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,32705,06/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,34384,07/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,33447,08/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,40487,09/01/15
Gesamtsumme alle HKL,52730,10/01/15
Irak,901,01/01/15
Irak,835,02/01/15
Irak,1052,03/01/15
Irak,1282,04/01/15
Irak,1382,05/01/15
Irak,1975,06/01/15
Irak,1987,07/01/15
Irak,1718,08/01/15
Irak,2454,09/01/15
Irak,4047,10/01/15
Kosovo,3034,01/01/15
Kosovo,6913,02/01/15
Kosovo,11147,03/01/15
Kosovo,4319,04/01/15
Kosovo,1781,05/01/15
Kosovo,1373,06/01/15
Kosovo,1205,07/01/15
Kosovo,625,08/01/15
Kosovo,622,09/01/15
Kosovo,619,10/01/15
Mazedonien,540,01/01/15
Mazedonien,547,02/01/15
Mazedonien,744,03/01/15
Mazedonien,617,04/01/15
Mazedonien,637,05/01/15
Mazedonien,984,06/01/15
Mazedonien,1285,07/01/15
Mazedonien,882,08/01/15
Mazedonien,879,09/01/15
Mazedonien,703,10/01/15
Nigeria,455,01/01/15
Nigeria,416,02/01/15
Nigeria,268,03/01/15
Nigeria,579,05/01/15
Nigeria,656,06/01/15
Nigeria,558,07/01/15
Nigeria,476,08/01/15
Pakistan,812,06/01/15
Pakistan,666,07/01/15
Pakistan,596,08/01/15
Pakistan,1059,09/01/15
Pakistan,1000,10/01/15
Serbien,2042,01/01/15
Serbien,1871,02/01/15
Serbien,1709,03/01/15
Serbien,1462,04/01/15
Serbien,1395,05/01/15
Serbien,1404,06/01/15
Serbien,1449,07/01/15
Serbien,1371,08/01/15
Serbien,1201,09/01/15
Serbien,861,10/01/15
Somalia,396,04/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",5340,01/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",4023,02/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",4420,03/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",4224,04/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",4810,05/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",7301,06/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",9138,07/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",10112,08/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",16544,09/01/15
"Syrien, Arabische Republik",28214,10/01/15
Ungeklärt,475,01/01/15
Ungeklärt,703,09/01/15
Ungeklärt,1164,10/01/15
```

I used the same header as in the example and double checked everything but the graph is still not plotted. This error shows up. Other threads on stack overflow could not help [image: Error Screenshot]

Edit 1
Here is my code also, but it should not be any different from the example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.chart {
  background: #fff;
}

p {
  font: 12px helvetica;
}


.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 10px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>


<div class="chart">
</div>

<script>

chart("ohne_postionanträge_monatlich_erst2015.csv", "orange");

var datearray = [];
var colorrange = [];


function chart(csvpath, color) {

if (color == "blue") {
  colorrange = ["#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#A6BDDB", "#D0D1E6", "#F1EEF6"];
}
else if (color == "pink") {
  colorrange = ["#980043", "#DD1C77", "#DF65B0", "#C994C7", "#D4B9DA", "#F1EEF6"];
}
else if (color == "orange") {
  colorrange = ["#B30000", "#E34A33", "#FC8D59", "#FDBB84", "#FDD49E", "#FEF0D9"];
}
strokecolor = colorrange[0];

var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y");

var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 30};
var width = document.body.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "remove")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "20")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("top", "30px")
    .style("left", "55px");

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height-10, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(colorrange);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.weeks);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);

var yAxisr = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y);

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("silhouette")
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.key; });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var graph = d3.csv(csvpath, function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = format.parse(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

  svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
      .call(yAxis.orient("right"));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis.orient("left"));

  svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.selectAll(".layer").transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
        return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
    })})

    .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
      mousex = d3.mouse(this);
      mousex = mousex[0];
      var invertedx = x.invert(mousex);
      invertedx = invertedx.getMonth() + invertedx.getDate();
      var selected = (d.values);
      for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
        datearray[k] = selected[k].date
        datearray[k] = datearray[k].getMonth() + datearray[k].getDate();
      }

      mousedate = datearray.indexOf(invertedx);
      pro = d.values[mousedate].value;

      d3.select(this)
      .classed("hover", true)
      .attr("stroke", strokecolor)
      .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px"),
      tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "visible");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
     svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("opacity", "1");
      d3.select(this)
      .classed("hover", false)
      .attr("stroke-width", "0px"), tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "hidden");
  })

  var vertical = d3.select(".chart")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "remove")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "19")
        .style("width", "1px")
        .style("height", "380px")
        .style("top", "10px")
        .style("bottom", "30px")
        .style("left", "0px")
        .style("background", "#fff");

  d3.select(".chart")
      .on("mousemove", function(){
         mousex = d3.mouse(this);
         mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
         vertical.style("left", mousex + "px" )})
      .on("mouseover", function(){
         mousex = d3.mouse(this);
         mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
         vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")});
});
}
</script>
```

Edit 2
Logging data
[image]

Comment: whats on line 122 on index_working.html ?

Comment: `var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));`

Comment: how do you read the data in ? what is data ?

Comment: I did some editing so you can see my code too

Comment: i read the data with the d3.csv function and data is parsed result of this function for d3. so it can handle the entries i suppose

Comment: try log data before line 122

Comment: it gives me objects with date, key and value. See Edit 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98356/discussion-between-thisoneguy-and-basedian).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stack method expects your data to be equally length-ed.  Each `key` must have the same `dates`.  For instance, if we only look at your first 3 keys (countries) and fixed the data to this:

```
key,value,date
Afghanistan,1129,01/01/15
Afghanistan,969,02/01/15
Afghanistan,885,03/01/15
Afghanistan,1119,04/01/15
Afghanistan,1151,05/01/15
Afghanistan,2051,06/01/15
Afghanistan,2104,07/01/15
Afghanistan,2270,08/01/15
Afghanistan,2724,09/01/15
Afghanistan,3770,10/01/15
Albanien,1598,01/01/15
Albanien,1735,02/01/15
Albanien,2955,03/01/15
Albanien,4743,04/01/15
Albanien,4864,05/01/15
Albanien,5837,06/01/15
Albanien,7547,07/01/15
Albanien,8234,08/01/15
Albanien,6624,09/01/15
Albanien,4549,10/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,0,01/01/15 //<-- this was missing
Bosnien und Herzegowina,370,02/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,380,03/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,472,04/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,382,05/01/15
Bosnien und Herzegowina,0,06/01/15 //<-- this was missing
Bosnien und Herzegowina,0,07/01/15 //<-- this was missing
Bosnien und Herzegowina,0,08/01/15 //<-- this was missing
Bosnien und Herzegowina,0,09/01/15 //<-- this was missing
Bosnien und Herzegowina,0,10/01/15 //<-- this was missing
```

Then the graph draws as [expected](http://plnkr.co/edit/D0bGmeQQa8V6Mx3QfJ93?p=preview).